# php exec command (or similar) to not wait for result

Tags: php, exec

I have a command I want to run, but I do not want PHP to sit and wait for the result.

```
<?php
echo "Starting Script";
exec('run_baby_run');
echo "Thanks, Script is running in background";
?>
```

Is it possible to have PHP not wait for the result.. i.e. just kick it off and move along to the next command.

I cant find anything, and not sure its even possible.  The best I could find was someone making a CRON job to start in a minute.

Comment: If you have to do this frequently, you might also be interested in a [JobQueue, like Gearman](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php).

Answer (score 148):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

> In order to execute a command and have it not hang your PHP script while
>   it runs, the program you run must not output back to PHP. To do this,
>   redirect both stdout and stderr to /dev/null, then background it.
>
> `> /dev/null 2>&1 &`
>
> In order to execute a command and have
>   it spawned off as another process that
>   is not dependent on the Apache thread
>   to keep running (will not die if
>   somebody cancels the page) run this:
>
> `exec('bash -c "exec nohup setsid your_command > /dev/null 2>&1 &"');`

Comment: Thank you so much! There are lots of "solutions" which don't actually work (The main browser thread is still waiting). Many solutions only tell about the "&" at the end which is not sufficient. That said, for me a simpler solution worked to: exec('nohup your_command > /dev/null 2>&1 &') was enough.

Comment: Why don't you need to also port `stdin` to /dev/null? Will a process' input being linked to a shell be enough to stop `nohup` from "disowning" the child process? (They do change `stdin` in this answer: http://superuser.com/questions/178587/how-do-i-detach-a-process-from-terminal-entirely)

Comment: also, why do you call both `nohup` and `setsid`? I can't find much information about which one is better or how they are different.. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247721/on-writing-a-linux-shell-script-to-safely-detach-programs-from-a-terminal)

Comment: @Christin: Your solution is working for my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25700904/how-to-run-php-code-in-the-background can you put an answer to that question. Then i can close that question with a green answer.

Comment: @Christin : Can you please take a look at my issue it seems same as my issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35331958/how-to-execute-script-in-silent-mode-to-get-rid-from-browser-hang-on

Comment: Is there a way to do this in Windows?

Comment: Thanks for this answer!  Although to be nit-picky, a comment on the English PHP docs isn't quite the same as an official PHP recommendation.

Comment: [setsid](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240646/why-we-use-setsid-while-daemonizing-a-process) to ignore dead parent makes [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) to ignore dead terminal redundant.

Comment: Super solutions. Thank you so much.

Comment: While I agree with the answer in general, it is not necessary (and usually not even a good idea) to pipe stdout and (especially) stderr to /dev/null.  Certainly pipe them to somewhere, but preferably this will be a permanent file, making mystery less likely when something doesn't work.

Answer (score 56):

You can run the command in the background by adding a `&` at the end of it as:

```
exec('run_baby_run &');
```

But doing this alone will hang your script because:

> If a program is started with exec function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

So you can redirect the stdout of the command to a file, if you want to see it later or to `/dev/null` if you want to discard it as:

```
exec('run_baby_run > /dev/null &');
```

Comment: Doesn't redirect stderr, and gets killed by a crashing webserver.

Answer (score 10):

This uses wget to notify a URL of something without waiting.

```
$command = 'wget -qO- http://test.com/data=data';
exec('nohup ' . $command . ' >> /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!', $pid);
```

This uses ls to update a log without waiting.

```
$command = 'ls -la > content.log';
exec('nohup ' . $command . ' >> /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!', $pid);
```

Comment: I think you are missing an `&` symbol between `2>&1` and `echo`, am I right?

Comment: Does nohup also keep the child running if the parent is killed?

Comment: @santiagoarizti yes, I fixed it as the code was not working otherwise

Answer (score 9):

I know this question has been answered but the answers i found here didn't work for my scenario ( or for Windows ).

I am using windows 10 laptop with PHP 7.2 in Xampp v3.2.4.

```
$command = 'php Cron.php send_email "'. $id .'"';
if ( substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows" )
{
    //windows
    pclose(popen("start /B " . $command . " 1> temp/update_log 2>&1 &", "r"));
}
else
{
    //linux
    shell_exec( $command . " > /dev/null 2>&1 &" );
}
```

This worked perfectly for me.

I hope it will help someone with windows. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you, just what I needed.

Comment: The system cannot find the path specified.
I think temp/update_log  this is not clear.can you explain?

Comment: @rahulsingh That file path is just the file from your current working directory, meaing, it assumes you have a folder name `temp` in your current directory with a file inside that folder called `upload_log`, that's it.

Comment: A slight variant of this works for me on Windows.
Instead of:
`pclose(popen("start /B " . $command . " 1> temp/update_log 2>&1 &", "r"));`
I used:
`pclose(popen("start /B " . $command . " 1> NUL 2>&1 &", "r"));`
And it works.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible ways to implement it.
The easiest way is direct result to dev/null

```
exec("run_baby_run > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

But in case you have any other operations to be performed you may consider [ignore_user_abort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php)
In this case the script will be running even after you close connection.

Answer (score 1):

> > "exec **nohup** setsid your_command"

the **nohup** allows your_command to continue even though the process that launched may terminate first.  If it does, the the SIGNUP signal will be sent to your_command causing it to terminate (unless it catches that signal and ignores it).

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/284443/819417), a child has to sign up for SIGHUP to be notified of its parent's death. A terminal tends to send the HUP signal on exit, though.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you may use the COM object:

```
if(class_exists('COM')) {
    $shell = new COM('WScript.Shell');
    $shell->Run($cmd, 1, false);
}
else {
    exec('nohup ' . $cmd . ' 2>&1 &');
}
```

Comment: There is no COM class in php

Comment: There is indeed. I use it myself. https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php