# form submit then process it in background

Tags: php, ajax, api

I have a question regarding background processing

I have a form that the visitor can fill out, and I use ajax.

when the customer click send the process page do like this

- 1 - include api 1
- 2 - include api 2
- 3-  include api 3
- 4- include mail file ( send mail using PhpMailler and Amazon web
  service mail )

the total process time of this page is 15 second due to api process time and the time that php mailer use to send the mail ::

What I want is a way to process my form in background , the visitor should redirect to page after submit and php file should be running in background

any ideas ?

thanks

Comment: 15 Seconds, I suggest you should have a look at the code. This much time on a form submission is, well doesn't seems okay. About your question yes its possible But with drawbacks. There's already some answers to this question. I'll see if I find it and link it here.

Comment: thanks, 
the code withour APIs it work very vast, even when I try to send email throw php not smtp it work very faster

Comment: Try this, `ignore_user_abort()` and `multi curl` will help you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124462/asynchronous-php-calls

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781934/not-waiting-for-response-from-an-ajax-request