# How can I run a PHP script in the background after pushing some data to it?

Tags: php, process, background, upload

I have an upload script that uploads images to a server. I need a script to run in the background after the image is uploaded and moved by `move_uploaded_file()`, but I need to send a filename and path to that file to the script (pretty much send some data).

How can I run a PHP script in the background after some data has been sent to it?

Notes: The files are uploaded via XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138374/close-a-connection-early

Comment: @Joseph Silber Is there a way to do this without closing the connection early?

Comment: I don't get it. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Joseph Silber A script runs and starts several background script processes. So script1.php script2.php etc would be executed but with data that I send it. I need this to bypass PHP's max execution time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First read this

[php exec command (or similar) to not wait for result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819398/php-exec-command-or-similar-to-not-wait-for-result/3819422#3819422)

It is basically pointing out that you need to create a script that takes two params (
filename, path)

Then you need to use the exec function

### Edit:

**As pointed out by Brent Baisle in the comments below, "nohup" must be added infront of the script to execute independently (with a different parent pid)**

```
exec('noup php scriptyoucreated.php '.$filename.' '.$path.' > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

This writes the output to dev/null, php should not block at this point, i have not tried, but in theory.

Comment: I believe exec() will indeed block. You could fork your process: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php

Comment: exec() only blocks if it is waiting for a response. Redirecting the output makes it unblocking. However, you need to include "nohup" in front the script you are running. Otherwise the script will die when the parent process ends. You don't want to fork under Apache.