# On writing a Linux shell script to safely detach programs from a terminal

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to write a Linux shell script (preferably bash),
supposedly named `detach.sh`, to safely detach programs from a terminal,
such that:

1. Invocation: `./detach.sh prog [arg1 arg2 ...]`.
2. Is `exec`-able, eg. by running this in your shell:

   ```
   exec ./detach.sh prog [arg1 arg2 ...]
   ```
3. With proper quoting (mainly handling of arguments containing whitespaces).
4. Discards the outputs (since they are unneeded).
5. Does not use `screen`, `tmux`, etc.
   (same reason with 4, plus no need for an extra babysitting process).
6. Uses (reasonably) portable commands and programs,
   and no things like `start-stop-daemon` which is quite distro-specific.

I have thought of several ways (shebang lines `#!/bin/bash` neglected
for the sake of briefness):

1. `nohup`:

   ```
   nohup "$@" >& /dev/null &
   ```
2. `disown`:

   ```
   "$@" >& /dev/null &
   disown
   ```
3. `setsid`:

   ```
   setsid "$@" >& /dev/null &
   ```
4. Using a subshell:

   ```
   ("$@" >& /dev/null &)
   ```
5. `nohup`/`setsid` combined with subshell:

   ```
   # Or alternatively:
   # (nohup "$@" >& /dev/null &)
   (setsid "$@" >& /dev/null &)
   ```

When using `gedit` as the test program (substituting the `"$@"` part),
condition 1 can be satisfied with all the above methods,
but condition 2 can be satisfied with none.

However, if an arbitrary program (but not a shell builtin) is appended to script 5,
all the conditions seem to be satisfied (at least for me in the `gedit` case).
For example:

```
(setsid "$@" >& /dev/null &)
# Not just `true' because it is also a shell builtin.
/bin/true
```

Anyone with an idea about an explanation of the above phenomenons
and how to correctly implement the requirements?

**EDIT:**

With condition 2, I mean the program should be detached from the terminal but runs as usual otherwise. For example, with the `gedit` case, the condition fails if `gedit` just exits immediately right after the process of the script has ended.

Comment: In what way does solution 5 not meet requirement 2, assuming you have the shebang?  Or, approximately equivalently, what does requirement 2 mean that it isn't satisfied by solution 5?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when `gedit` is run in background?  Since `gedit` is an editor that runs interactively, but a background process is, more or less by definition, something that runs without user interaction, maybe the trouble is your choice of test program.  Handling X11-based programs is rather different from handling compilers and the like.  What do you see happening when you run `gedit` in the background?

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect explanation of my idea. I meant "detaching" when saying "backgrounding". Please see the updated version of this question. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The string "shebang lines `#!/bin/bash` neglected to save disk space for StackExchange's server" takes up more disk space than the actual shebangs.

Comment: @Pumbaa80: Perhaps the reason should be "for the sake of briefness" :)

Comment: AFAIK, "detaching" isn't really a term that means anything - I've never heard it used outside the context of screen or tmux, so I really don't know what you want to happen to the process when it's "detached". `disown` works on the shell side - it either tells the shell to not send HUP, or removes the job from the job table, in which case I'm not sure what `exec` is doing for you, because you're replacing the shell. Nohup is an external program that masks the HUP signal basically.

Comment: @ormaaj: Here by saying "detach", I mean to redirect the stdout/stderr of a process to `/dev/null`, make the process independent from the invoking shell, and thus let the process run as usual even afer the shell has exited.

Comment: @ormaaj: The `exec` is present here because sometimes it is just needed to replace a shell. For example, to customise a menu program used to launch (by `exec`-ing) other programs, it might be convenient to launch something detached using `detach.sh` in the configuration file of the menu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upon closer investigation, these previously unnoticed facts were revealed:

1. Both scripts 3 and 5 (the `setsid` variant only) will
   satisfy all the conditions if a `/bin/true` is appended to the script.
2. These scripts, as modified in fact 1, will work as well if
   `/bin/true` is replaced with `for i in {0..9999}; do :; done`.

Therefore we can conclude that:

- (From fact 1)

  Multiple levels of detaching (as in script 5) is unnecessary,
  and the key is to use the right utility (`setsid`).
- (From fact 2)

  A suitable delay before bash exit is necessary for the success of the script.
  (Calling external program `/bin/true` consumes some time,
  just like the pure-bash time consumer `for i in {0..9999}; do :; done`.)

  I have not looked at the source code, but I guess a possible explanation
  is that bash may exit before `setsid` finishes configuring the execution
  environment of the program to run, if an appropriate delay is not applied.

And finally, an optimal solution should be

```
#!/bin/bash
setsid "$@" >& /dev/null &
sleep 0.01
```

**EDIT 1**:

The necessity of a delay has been explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37134825/1346709). Many thanks to @wilx!

**EDIT 2**:

(Thanks to @MateiDavid) we seem to have forgotten to redirect the standard input, and a better way would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
setsid "$@" >& /dev/null < /dev/null &
```

Comment: Try leaving out the backgrounding and the delay: `setsid "$@" >&- 2>&- <&-`.

Comment: @MateiDavid: Many thanks!  I have updated my answer, but the backgrounding still seems necessary for bash.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do `setsid "$@" >& /dev/null & wait` so that the controlling terminal does not disappear before `setsid` manages to fork the child.

**UPDATE**

It seems to me that this works both on command line and as argument of `-c`:

```
(setsid tail -F /var/log/messages >& /dev/null) & disown
```

Comment: Many thanks :) I have updated my own answer to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: The explanation is very reasonable. But `bash -c 'setsid sleep 1 >& /dev/null & wait'` somehow blocks (while it does not block in interactive `bash`), so does not solve the problem for now.

Comment: But `$ exec bash -c '(setsid geany >& /dev/null) & disown'` fails; I think it might be better to look at why `setsid`'d process has a PID different from `setsid` in an interactive shell (but the same PID in a non-interactive shell).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a UNIX daemon process (i.e., a process that has no controlling terminal and that is its own [session](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group) leader).  The `setsid` command should do this for you, but you are responsible for closing all file descriptors that are open on the terminal you are abandoning.  This can be done by redirecting them to `/dev/null` or using the shell's syntax for closing file descriptors (e.g., `2>&-` and `0<&-` in Bash).

Comment: Thanks, but I think script 3 and 5 (see my question) have both done these, while still don't solve the problem. In addition, the cause of the phenomenon that a call to `/bin/true` or so solves the problem is still unexplained.