# Linux background a running app

Tags: linux

I have a Debian server, and I wanted to run a script in the background forever even if the console is closed.

My problem is that I can't just use this cmd : `nohup my script > /dev/null 2>&1 &` 
Because I need to use some cmd line inside the script running as well such as /start to initialize my script.

Is it possible to put a running script in the background and make it up running forever ?
I have tried Ctrl + z and bg, but when I close my console its just stop working..

Comment: The term you are looking for is called "detaching". Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247721/on-writing-a-linux-shell-script-to-safely-detach-programs-from-a-terminal

Comment: Also google a bit about the term "double fork magic".

Comment: you might like to look at the ``screen`` program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
screen -SU myscript
# opens new shell
# run you script here
# press ctrl + a, d (ctrl+a then just d) to leave your script running in background

# to open the screen again type:
screen -x myscript
```