Trigger command line from Web page?
I have a php script that works just fine when it's run via SSH in the terminal. However, my goal is to have a button on a web page that will trigger the same script to run.
Let's call the script foo.php and when passed with parameters will be foo.php -b 35
Then my web page will have a form that would run this script.
<form action="foo.php" method="post" target="_blank">


use shell_exec on a file called run_foo.php like $output = shell_exec('php.exe foo.php -b 35')

What you've already got here will work just fine, simply update the script to use a default value of 35 when it's not explicitly specified. (Or, if desired, to take the value from the form post via $_POST['b'].) Always avoid shell_exec() when possible, it is unneeded and problematic here.

no luck the PHP script calls:
$output = shell_exec('/usr/local/php74/bin/php //home/customer/www/domain.com/public_html/PPLG/DWR.php');
and it doesn't work

doesn't work how, exactly? What error do you get? Did you check the content of $output?

P.S. You didn't say why you want to run foo.php from the command-line, and not just execute it directly via the webserver? What does the script do, exactly?

It times out in the web server, it compiles a ton of data and makes an excel spreadsheet...

Then if you call it from the webserver there's a good chance it will also hang that. You haven't said yet what "doesn't work" actually meant in practice when you ran this, but you may want to look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819398/php-exec-command-or-similar-to-not-wait-for-result

Or you may want to consider some kind of disconnected architecture, where you have a cron job calling the script every few minutes, but it only actually does something useful if there's a job logged for it to process - jobs could be logged in a database table, or a queue system, or whatever, which it would read from when the script starts. In this case, a job could be logged by you submitting a form to run_foo.php, which would log a job rather than trying to run foo.php directly. Then, next time cron triggers foo.php it will read the job log and start processing.

@ADyson My script I want to run does a lot of data processing to create an excel file. I am using a Linux server and the script can take minutes (15 or more, depending on the data set). THe web interface  presents a picker that the user selects what they want to run (this will be the parameter sent to the executed script). I'm baffled....

That's why I suggested the disconnected architecture using cron, in my last comment. In that design, the long-running script is run by cron, in the background, and therefore you don't have the problem with timeouts etc.

@ADyson whould you have any sample code that I could use?

Sample code for what specifically? You already have the script to create the excel file, so presumably you don't need that. Are you asking for code to write something into a database table, and then to read from it? Or what?
